# NGP mechanism vs the simple carbocation mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbocation

**Question:**

> Predict the product of: ($\ce{C^*}$ is a $\ce{C^14}$ carbon)
>
> [image]

**My attempt:**

I simply assumed the super-leaving group $\ce{-OTs^-}$ would leave, forming a primary ethylbenzene carbocation. That would rearrange via a hydride shift to form a secondary carbocation on $\ce{C^*}$ atom. The nucleophilic $\ce{-OH}$ group of the $\ce{-COOH}$ group will then attack and lose a proton to form 1-phenylethylethanoate (with the ester linkage at the $\ce{C^*}$ carbon):

[image]

However, my book has instead taken a different route. In the very first step, after $\ce{OTs-}$ leaves, they have taken the NGP mechanism and formed this transition state:

[image]

and said that now the $\ce{OAc-}$ will attack either of the two carbons (in that trigonal ring). Hence, **according to their logic**, **both types of 1-phenylethylethanoate will be formed** - one with the ester linkage at the $\ce{C^*}$ carbon, and the other at the $\ce{C}$ carbon.

**My question:**

I have confirmed from Clayden (Chapter 37 Rearrangements page 976) that the product ratio is indeed 50:50. So:

- Why is the NGP mechanism being favored here over the other mechanism I described, even though the NGP mechanism involves a loss of aromaticity?
- Are there other cases where the NGP mechanism dominates over the simple carbocation mechanisms, or is this the only such case?

---

**Source**: MS Chouhan; Advanced Problems In Organic Chemistry; 11th ed; Q16 in  Alkyl Halides (Substitution)

Comment: At some level, the mechanism must be similar to that described (losing aromaticity etc) as that predicts the observed results. Not the other way around, surely.

Comment: Your second question doesn't make much sense. If there was only a unique case there wouldn't be even such a name as NGP. Every time when neighbouring group can delocalise carbocation it does that.

Comment: The experimental results dictate the choice of mechanism. The spiro cation is a stabilized cation, even if aromaticity is interrupted and it is less stable than its precursor. Is there an electrophilic aromatic substitution that doesn't interrupt aromaticity?

Comment: Hydride shift? Do you really want to form a primary carbocation?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis I mentioned that "That would rearrange via a hydride shift to form a **secondary** carbocation on C* atom", so I am not really sure why you think I'm forming a primary carbocation instead :/

Comment: But you are forming a primary carbocation as an intermediate which is not stable. Or are you proposing the hydride shift and OTs removal in a concerted step?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Well, obviously, in both of the mechanisms I showed above, $\ce{-OTs-}$ will be removed and a primary carbocation will be formed. This would then rearrange to a secondary carbocation in my mechanism, and form a spiro carbocation in the second mechanism. So, I still don't get what you're saying? (and what is a "concerted step"?)

Answer (score 6):

From Clayden (Chapter 37 Rearrangements page 976):

> Intramolecular reactions (including participation of a neighbouring group) that give three-, 
>   five-, or six-membered rings are usually faster than intermolecular reactions.

It also gives the exact same example as your question:

> [image]

Notice that both products are given to be **exactly** 50% each.

NGP is very often faster than bimolecular reactions as for the latter to take place two molecules have to collide first.

1:1 ratio can be attributed to the fact that in NGP the transition state involves loss of aromaticity **BUT** NGP supports the ionization of the starting material.

There are a lot of examples  this one reaction isn't a black swan. Interested readers may see chapter 36: Participation, rearrangement and fragmentation in Clayden to find more details and examples.

Comment: I added a few things. You may wanna delete your 2 bullet points. The data is exactly 50:50 given in book.

Comment: I don't understand why NGP is favored even over losing aromaticity. And both of your reasons don't make sense. Can you please give a page number where I can read about "favored by high entropy changes"? And what exactly do you mean by "The ionization of the starting material?

Comment: @Gaurang See clayden CH31 pg 806-807 for the ring thing . Ionization of the starting material means ngp doesn't depend upon a collision so it ionizes faster.

Comment: Pg 806-807 Ch31 doesn't mention "entropy" anywhere. And $\ce{OTs-}$ is a good leaving group, I doubt if it even needs any collisions to leave.

Comment: @Gaurang my south asian edition does

Comment: Please quote some relevant details from it into your answer.

Comment: @Gaurang That's a pretty big topic

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't need any collisions to leave you gotta break the bond it's easy for it to leave having an NGP speeds it up faster than a collision

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74426/discussion-between-avnish-kabaj-and-gaurang-tandon).